# ORM связь Kohana

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Существует 2 модели

```
class Model_Product extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'categories' => array(
            'model' => 'categorie',
            'foreign_key' => 'parent',
        ),
    );  
}

class Model_Categorie extends ORM {
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'product' => array(
            'model'         => 'product',
            'foreign_key'   => 'code',
        )
    );  
}
```

Связи один ко многим и много к одному. У одной категории может быть много продуктов
Структура таблиц следующая

```
Products
id|name|art_num|parent|price|

Categories
id|p_id|name_cat|code
```

Бок в том, что foreign_key в Model_Product указывает на связь parent с id таблицы categories. А необходимо связь parent с code. Как это сделать?

Запрос $product->categories->name_cat берется не по code, а по id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если вот так?

```
class Model_Categorie extends ORM {

    protected $_primary_key = 'code'; // суть в этом

    // а дальше идут связи
}
```